# Toggle model for a specific Vue child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have 1 parent and 2 types of child components for a navbar of my application.

Parent Vue component has the following code:

```
<template>
    <div class="be-submenu__inner">
        <ul class="be-submenu__categories">
            <category-tab name="Events" @setActive="toggleActive"></category-tab>
            <category-tab name="Articles" @setActive="toggleActive"></category-tab>
        </ul>
        <news-cards></news-cards>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import NewsCards from './NewsCards.vue'
import CategoryTab from './CategoryTab.vue'

export default {
    name: 'be-nav-submenu-news',
    data() {
        return{
            queryCategory: null,
            posts: ''
        }
    },
    methods: 
        toggleActive: function (selectedTab) {
            console.log(selectedTab)
        }
    },
    components: {
        CategoryTab,
        NewsCards
    }
}
</script>
```

`category-tab` components:

```
<template>
    <li class="be-submenu__category">
        <a :class="[titleStyle, { 'is-active': isActive }]" @mouseover="setActive">
            {{ this.name }}
        </a>
    </li>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'be-category-tab',
        data() {
            return {
                titleStyle: 'be-submenu__category-link'
            }
        },
        props: {
            name: {
                required: true
            },
            isActive: {
                required: false,
                default: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            setActive: function () {
                this.$emit('setActive', this.name) 
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

What I want to do is to update tabs state once I put my cursor over one of them. Let's say I hover the second tab and its property `isActive` gets set to `true`. Other components becomes inactive and `<news-cards>` component's content also get updated according to a tab I select.

I assume that I have to track all the child elements with `'be-category-tab'` name somehow and update their state once the custom event is triggered. Vue documentation got me confused about custom events, so now I am not even sure if I use it right at all.

Could you give me a clue what could be my next step here? Or maybe I should use something else, but custom events.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide small complete example in jsfiddle or sth like that?

Comment: @SLYcee, I did. Has to be a mistake, when I was removing unnecessary code for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```js
Vue.component('category-tab', {
  template: '<li class="be-submenu__category">' +
    '<a :class="[titleStyle, { \'is-active \': isActive }]" @mouseover="setActive">' +
    '{{ this.name }} {{ this.isActive }}' +
    '</a></li>',

  data() {
    return {
      titleStyle: 'be-submenu__category-link'
    }
  },
  props: {
    name: {
      required: true
    },
    isActive: {
      default: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setActive: function() {
      this.$emit('setactive')
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('news-cards', {
  template: '<div>New Cards : {{ proptest }}</div>',
  props: { proptest: { default: ''} }
});


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      categoriesTab: [{
        name: 'Events',
        isActive: false
      }, {
        name: 'Articles',
        isActive: false
      }, {
        name: 'Other category...',
        isActive: false
      }],
      queryCategory: null,
      posts: '',
      name: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    deactiveAllCategories: function()  {
      for (var i = 0, length = this.categoriesTab.length; i < length; i++)  {
        this.categoriesTab[i].isActive = false;
      }
    },
    setActive: function(category) {
      this.deactiveAllCategories();
      this.name = category.name;
      category.isActive = true;
    }
  },
});
```

```css
.be-submenu__category{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.is-active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.5/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="be-submenu__inner">
    <ul class="be-submenu__categories">

      <category-tab v-for="(category, index) in categoriesTab" @setactive="setActive(category)" :name="category.name" :is-active="category.isActive" :key="category">
      </category-tab>

    </ul>
    <news-cards :proptest="name"></news-cards>
  </div>
</div>
```